# Count Referer in laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel

I build a `referral system` Using `Laravel` and `VueJS`. i want `count referral` each users.

I implement count it from **`User Model`**

```
public function getCountReferrerAttribute()
{
    $user = User::where('referred_by', auth()->user()->name)->count();

    return $user;
}
```

And i try to get it from `Vuejs`

[image]

Its show `Referrer Count` for Every User...

**`User Schema`**

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('referral_code')->unique()->nullable();
    $table->string('referred_by')->nullable();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are calling this function for every user on your table, your query is getting all user that is referred by the currently logged in user because of `auth()->user()->name`, instead your function should use the name of the user itself.

So it will look something like this

```
public function getCountReferrerAttribute()
{
    $user = User::where('referred_by', $this->name)->count();

    return $user;
}
```

Comment: sorry, but how can i pass `$userName` to `Vuejs`??

Comment: Hold on.. i just noticed this is an attribute accessor, my answer is not going to work. Can you please clarify where you are putting this function?

Comment: I put this `function` in `User Model`.

Comment: @z3r0 I have modified my answer, please give it another try